# undoing accidental git merge without regressing history

Tags: git

I did something stupid and accidently merged a topic branch into my master branch and then pushed it live to github (where others have pulled). Just to make sure it was a completely moronic mistake, I pulled it out to my production servers.

I've hung my head in shame for the appropriate amount of time and now I need to figure out how to effectively roll back the code commits while progressing the commit history.

To get my production code to the correct checkout, I ran `git checkout hashoflettersandnumbers` and that's the commit I want the production HEAD to be.

I run `git reset hashoflettersandnumbers` and then git clean to remove the changes from that commit going forward, but I can't seem to get that code to be the HEAD of the master branch and make a fresh commit.

Comment: +1 for "mak[ing] sure it was a completely moronic mistake". [My recent] Misery loves company.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `git revert` on each of the branches.  This will create a new commit that preserves your mistake for all eternity, but gives you back the same tree as you had before you merged.

For example, if 123456 is the merge commit...

```
$ git checkout master
$ git revert 123456
$ git checkout topic-branch
$ git revert 123456
```

This assumes that this wasn't a "fast-forward" merge.

Comment: thanks @dietrich. For my own reference when I google this next time, it's safest, and most intuitive to get back to a stable commit, one commit at a time and using the flag --no-commit to prevent one-at-a-time commits while backing out. Also, use -m 1 for merge commits.